# How to inject properties into a spring bean from Main class

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring with my application, and I'm able to inject some properties from some file on a class path into my app and everything works perfectly. i.e.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I can use `${any.property.from.application.properties}` in my spring context. And in my main class :

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
```

It works as well, my question is how do I inject property file location in the spring context without it being there at first, I want to make my app configurable. If I'm executing my app from `C:\dir` or `/user/home/dir` I assume that in the application context the value should be either `C:\application.properties` or `/user/home/dir/application.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem sometime back. My requirement was the the property files is not bundled inside the application (and hence not in classpath). The file could be at any location in file system. 
 Here is how I solved it,

1. Define an environment variable the value of which points to the location of application.properties.
2. Lets say we have a env variable APP_PROP_HOME with value /user/home/dir/
3. Now while defining ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, define the locations as follows

I am reusing your example

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file://${APP_PROP_HOME}/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The Spring resolves ${APP_PROP_HOME} to the value stored in corresponding env property and your application is configured at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, You want to use an external properties file(i.e File is not in the application runtime class path). If that is the case you need to use the file tag

```
 <value>file:///c:\application.properties</value>
```

Comment: how will I inject this to application context from Main class?

Comment: You can inject a property location using some things like this, make sure you add this property to the property configurer <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true">, You can do this PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = (PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)ctx.getBean(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
  Resource rsc = new FileSystemResource("file:///C:\\Applications\\one.properties");
  configurer.setLocation(rsc);, I am not sure why you are doing this but If you inject the property file after spring container boot up, you cannot the use properties in the context file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` to inject values from the env.  Example:

```
private someFoo;

@Value("${systemProperties.someFoo}")
public void setSomeParam(String someParam) {
   this.someFoo = someParam;
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work in my PostConstructionHook what are requirements for access to these variables?