# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with Tomcat & ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with Tomcat & ContextLoaderListener.

This works (with the name of the properties file hardcoded):

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:properties/test.properties"/>
</bean>
```

But this (with the name of the properties file replaced with ${env}):

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:properties/${env}.properties"/>
</bean>
```

[Thread-2] 15:50:16 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [properties/${env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I know the file is there since it works when I hardcode it.

I have tried using -Denv=test when starting Tomcat and setting an environment variable. I have the same thing working outside of Tomcat using my own main method instead of ContextLoaderListener.

What might I be doing wrong? Can I achieve the same thing using an entry in context.xml or web.xml instead of -Denv=test?

Thanks

PS I have also tried:

```
<bean id="initialcorePropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment">
        <value type="boolean">true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="corePropertyConfigurer" depends-on="initialcorePropertyConfigurer" lazy-init="true"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:properties/${env}.properties" />
</bean>
```

but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a property placeholder in your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer definition.  Chicken-and-the-egg.

You could however use `#{ systemProperties['env'] }`

Or you could subclass `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and override `setLocation()` to handle a placeholder.

Comment: I do have a property placeholder in your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer definition working just fine. But only with my own main method, not using Tomcat & ContextLoaderListener. 

Also, even if I use 2 PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as in the end of my email, it still gives the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the ${env} to #{ systemProperties['env'] } as per your suggestion and it resolved the error. I'm still not clear why it works with my own main but not in Tomcat & ContextLoaderListener.

Answer (score 0):

Set the complete location like `-DpropFileLocation=classpath:env1.properties` or `-DpropFileLocation=classpath:env2.properties` instead of just a part of it:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="location" value="${propFileLocation}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: After all its a hack there are cleaner ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variables CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS to -Denv=test. The best way to do this is to create a setenv.bat (or .sh if you are on unix) and add this environment variable definition there.

It won't take effect if you pass it as an argument to startup.bat (.sh), which I assume what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried that and doesn't seem to make a difference. I already added a servlet that does a simple

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried that and doesn't seem to make a difference. I already added a servlet that does a simple System.getProperties() and then prints them out. I see the property env in that list. So it is available inside my code in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820724/how-to-inject-properties-into-a-spring-bean-from-main-class) on this forum where in a property file was needed to be externalized. Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820724/how-to-inject-properties-into-a-spring-bean-from-main-class/6828106#6828106). It think your problem is similar, instead of pass env as system variable, set it as env variable .

Comment: Thanks. I already tried using a env variable and got the same error.