# How to get a tomcat Environment variable in a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I try to get an Environment variable specified in Tomcat's `server.xml` in a 'PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer' located in my `jpa-spring.xml` file.

So far, the setup looks as follows:

Tomcat `server.xml`

```
<Environment description="Identifies the server environement" 
             name="server-env" 
             type="java.lang.String" 
             value="dev" />
```

The in `WebContent/META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="server-env" global="server-env" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Which is referenced in `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml` like:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>Identifies server environement</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>server-env</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>java.lang.String</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<!-- Spring Integration -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/jpa-spring.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And in `/WEB-INF/config/jpa-spring.xml` I try to get that variable as a replacement:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/config/db.${server-env}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is a setup I put together using information from several articles found on the web.

However, I get an error like ...

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'server-env' in [WEB-INF/config/db.${server-env}.properties] as system property: neither system property nor environment variable found
05 Nov 2011 14:45:13,385 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
ERROR Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/db.${server-env}.properties]
```

... when starting tomcat.

What is the right approach to achieve what I am looking for?

I know that this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820724/how-to-inject-properties-into-a-spring-bean-from-main-class/6828106#6828106), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476615/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-with-tomcat-contextloaderlistener) question. However, I even couldn't figure it out with the information from these answers.

Comment: Which version of Spring you are using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my suggestion

- With the current set up, its really going to be complicated to read JNDI property `server-env` and use the same to load the property file.
- The way you have assembled the spring application (and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`), spring will try to look for the property `server-env` first in OS environment then in java system properties (passed from command using -D option). It finds it at neither of these places and hence fails.
- So currently the easiest way out right now is to pass the value of server-env form command prompt of your application server (where you invoke java ; typical syntax would be -Dserver-env=dev). I leave this to you to figure out.
- if above option appears a bit complicated, another easier way out is set an environment variable with name server-env to its appropriate values (on Windows its `set server-env=dev`. Plz check respect OS documentations for this).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I defined my `server-env` variable in `catalina.properties` and can get it with the usual `${server-env}` syntax. Really simple and and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Those `Environment` elements are setting up JNDI. Getting values out of JNDI isn't supported, by default, by any simple syntactic sugar in Spring.

http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=35474#179220

might give you some useful ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the stuff mentioned in the thread is a bit to advanced for my current knowledge in this area. Had to go with a simpler solution (see comment above) for this time.